# Bubble sort 2D string array

Tags: c#

How can I **bubble sort** a **2D string array** **by their lenght**? In the array's zeroth column there are random generated messages and in the first column there are random generated priorities.

```
string[,] array = new string[50, 2];
            Random r = new Random();
            int number = 0;
            int space = 0;
            double fontossag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                string message = "";
                int hossz = r.Next(10,51);
                for (int h = 0; h < hossz; h++)
                {
                    number = r.Next(0,101);
                    space = r.Next(0, 101);
                    if (number<=50)
                    {
                        message += (char)r.Next(97,122);
                    }
                    else if(number >= 50)
                    {
                        message += (char)r.Next(65, 90);
                    }
                    if (space<=10)
                    {
                        message += " ";
                    }
                }
                for (int f = 0; f < 50; f++)
                {
                    fontossag = r.NextDouble() * (10.0);                    
                }
                array[i, 0] += message;
                array[i, 1] += fontossag;
            }
```

I want to sort the array by the random generated messages length.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts to solve your problem. There are many questions about how to implement a bubble sort in C# on Stack Overflow, and you need to show how this question is different from all of those.

Comment: if you need help understanding how bubble sort works, I suggest you [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4) that shows people dancing while solving it

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the part about prior research and describing the problem. "I Tried X and it didn't work" is not a very helpful problem description.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please? It's unclear what the *sorted* **2D** array is.

Comment: Edited, thanks the feedback.

Comment: Why would you bubble-sort in the first place? Under what circumstances would it be an efficient algorithm?

Comment: @Charlieface it's a great programming exercise, I bet you ever had to implement it while learning coding

Comment: @Charlieface This exercise was in my exam and unfortunately I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my method to Bubble sort on the first column length:

```
public static string[,] BubbleSortStringByLength(string[,] array)
{
  int num = array.GetLength(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (array[j, 0].Length > array[j + 1, 0].Length)
      {
        // swap first column
        string tmp = array[j, 0];
        array[j, 0] = array[j + 1, 0];
        array[j + 1, 0] = tmp;
        // swap second column
        tmp = array[j, 1];
        array[j, 1] = array[j + 1, 1];
        array[j + 1, 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

You can download the Visual Studio solution [on GitHub](https://github.com/fredatgithub/BubbleSortArrays)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compare lengths of 1st columns and swap rows to ensure descending priority:

```
   for (bool hasWork = true; hasWork;) {
     hasWork = false;

     for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0) - 1; ++row) {
       int priority1 = array[row, 0]?.Length ?? -1;
       int priority2 = array[row + 1, 0]?.Length ?? -1;

       // if we have wrong order...
       if (priority1 < priority2) {
         // we should keep on working to sort the array
         hasWork = true;

         // and swap incorrect rows
         for (int column = 0; column < array.GetLength(1); ++column)
           (array[row, column], array[row + 1, column]) = 
             (array[row + 1, column], array[row, column]);  
       }
     }
   }
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hBMfBE) yourself

Comment: No, actually I want to compare the zeroth column (generated chars) and then I want to sort it as descent by their lenght.

Comment: @Tomikamo: I see, I've edited the answer: now I compare lengths of first column to ensure descending order